# What is the relationship between oom_score and badness?

Tags: linux, kernel, out-of-memory

Whilst reading both https://lwn.net/Articles/391222/ and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html I have come across the terms `oom_score` and badness. Both numbers have the same basic meaning; the higher they are, the more likely the associated task is to be OOM-killed when the host is under memory pressure.

What is the relationship (if any) between the two numbers?

EDIT: My guess is `oom_score` = max(badness + `oom_score_adj`, 0) but I haven't found any proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is:

> oom_score = badness * 1000 / totalpages

based on the kernel code https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/base.c#L549.

```
static int proc_oom_score(struct seq_file *m, struct pid_namespace *ns,
              struct pid *pid, struct task_struct *task)
{
    unsigned long totalpages = totalram_pages + total_swap_pages;
    unsigned long points = 0;

    points = oom_badness(task, NULL, NULL, totalpages) *
                    1000 / totalpages;
    seq_printf(m, "%lu\n", points);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I feel the proc man page has a confusing description of badness within the `/proc/[pid]/oom_score_adj` section. I think in that description, the definition of badness is `oom_score`-`oom_score_adj` rather than the output of the badness function [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.17/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L149)

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks @Eugene!